# javascript fails in firefox but works fine in IE

Tags: javascript

my code

```
function   hide()
{
  var lblclear= document.getElementById("<%=Label1.ClientID%>"); 
  if(lblclear!= null) {
    lblclear.value="";
    lblclear.innerText="";
    lblclear.outerText="";
  }
}
```

on  button click  i am calling this  function

the above  function works  **fine in IE**  it is  clearing  my label text value
 in **firefox  browser** it is not clearing  my label text  value

can  any one help me  out
  thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that innerText and outerText is not supported on Firefox.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0460__DOM-Node/GetouterTextvalueforatagFirefoxdoesnotsupporttheouterText.htm

In order to hide this you can remove it (as that looks like what you are doing) or, preferably, using css, either the element.style properties or set className, but you can set the visibility or display to a value that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`innerText` will only work in IE, for other browser you should use `innerHTML`

```
function   hide()
{
  var lblclear= document.getElementById("<%=Label1.ClientID%>"); 
  if(lblclear!= null) {
    lblclear.value="";

    if (document.all) { // check if IE
      lblclear.innerText="";
      lblclear.outerText="";
    }
    else{  // other browsers
      lblclear.innerHTML="";
      lblclear.outerHTML=""; // updated. thanks @cdmckay
    }

  }
}
```

please check [working example](http://jsbin.com/oviro)

Comment: Don't you mean `outerHTML` for the second line of the `else`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to Alert in your function to see if your function is even getting called.